# Primefaces Datatable column width - intended behavior or broken?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

There are a lot of questions on SO regarding the primefaces datatable (in my case `6.1`)

A lot of people seem to have an issue where adding `style="width:XYZpx"` will not actually influence the column width of the given element.

Now, I've noticed that in 100% of cases I was able to "fix" this by assigning this style tag to every defined `<p:column>` tag. Is this intended behavior, or just broken?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use <p:column> attribute width and set it to px/% (<p:column width="25%"> ... </p:column>)

Comment: Ah, I see. So I've just been using it wrong. Welp, time for some refractoring.